# How do I install a package to a custom path for my framework?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using composer version 1.0-dev

I read https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md and https://github.com/composer/installershave

I have a custom module in bitbucket with this simple composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "mybitbucketuser/base",
    "type": "puppet-module",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "~1.0"
    }
}
```

In my main project I have this composer.json:

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://bitbucket.org/mybitbucketuser/fluzu-base.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "mybitbucketuser/base": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "modules/{$name}/": ["mybitbucketuser/base"]
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with this too:

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
        "modules/{$name}/": ["type:puppet-module"]
    }
}
```

All seems works fine but composer install the module in the default **vendor** dir instead in **modules** dir.

Whats wrong? Thanks.

By the way, I'm using type puppet-module but in reality is a [phalcon](http://phalconphp.com/en/) module.

Comment: Doesn't look wrong so far, it even should work without the `extra` section because of the type set to `puppet-module`. Did you try to remove the vendor folder completely? `rm -rf vendor/` and then reinstall all dependencies `composer update -v`? This sometimes helped me.

Comment: I did `rm composer.lock` and `rm -rf vendor/`more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a test and it worked. Here is a simple example where `hello-world` is a package and `hello-world-test` requires that package.

#### Folder structure

```
/
  hello-world/
    src/
      HelloWorld/
        SayHello.php
    composer.json

  hello-world-test/
    composer.json
```

---

#### /hello-world/src/HelloWorld/SayHello.php

```
<?php 

namespace HelloWorld;

class SayHello
{
    public static function world()
    {
        return 'Hello World, Composer!';
    }
}
```

#### /hello-world/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "me/hello-world",
    "type": "puppet-module",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "~1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "HelloWorld": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I ran

```
cd hello-world
git init
git add *
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git tag -a 1.0.0 -m "first stable version"
```

> **Note:** Composer expects a git repository here and also a version tag when the `minimum-stability` is set to stable. We can omit the tag if we set `minimum-stability` to `dev`.

---

#### /hello-world-test/composer.json

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "../hello-world"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "me/hello-world": "*"
    }
}
```

Then I ran

```
cd hello-world-test
composer install
```

Composer now automatically created a `vendor` folder for `composer/installers` and a `modules` folder for our `hello-world` package. The `modules` folder is created because of [`"type": "puppet-module"`](https://github.com/composer/installers/blob/master/src/Composer/Installers/PuppetInstaller.php) in our package.

Answer (score -1):

[Composer Packages Custom Installer plugin](https://github.com/farhanwazir/cpcinstaller), This will fulfill your needs. Just FORK it and add your instructions in config directory under src/Installer [CPCInstaller](https://github.com/farhanwazir/cpcinstaller) will do everything for you.